# A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected ActionLink in button

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

I am trying to turn a button into a Action Link, the link takes me to another page however I need to send `new { id = item.Id }` to my other page and I don't know how else to do this:

```
            @foreach (var item in Model.CurrentPost.Tags)
    {
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <a href="@Html.ActionLink("" + item.Name + "", "GetPostsByTag", "Post", new { id = item.Id }, null)" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
                @item.Name
            </a>
        </div>

    }
```

I am getting this error:

> A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the
>   client (<).

When clicking the button the url that it tried to take me to was:

```
http://localhost:52202/Post/MainDetails/<a href="/Post/GetPostsByTag?id=54">Picture</a>
```

Have no idea why picture is appended on the end or the href, it should be:

```
http://localhost:52202/Post/MainDetails/GetPostsByTag?id=54
```

Comment: `@Html.ActionLink()` generates an `<a>` tag. You do not need to wrap it in another `<a>` tag. - just use  `@Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "GetPostsByTag", "Post", new { id = item.Id }, null)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke do you know how to solve this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29907772/conflict-with-reference-constraint-in-enitity-framework-sql-mvc

Comment: The first comment in that question should solve the issue (setting the `DeleteRule` to `cascade`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@Html` is used to generate HTML, matching methods in `@Url` (like [`UrlHelper.Action`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492758%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) ) should be used to generates urls like `href` attribute.

So to fix the problem either use `@Url.Action` if you need detailed control over resulting HTML

```
<a href='@Url.Action("" + item.Name, "GetPostsByTag", "Post", 
       new { id = item.Id }, null)' class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
            @item.Name
        </a>
```

Or use [`@Html.ActionLink`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) to generate whole `<a>` tag:

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "GetPostsByTag", "Post", new { id = item.Id },
         new {class="btn btn-default btn-lg"})
```

Comment: Side note: please note that ActionLink allows to set attributes on `A` tag (like in this case "class"), so original code does not necessary need completely custom rendering.